# Is there any way to import an external file in Google Colab?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

Hello I would like to import an txt file from a GitHub. Is there any way to import this file in Google Colab?
I don't want to download the file and import this one because when I will open the Google Colab again it won't be

Answer (score 1):

I found a way in case it helps someone:

```
url = 'https://...'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('data.txt', 'wb').write(r.content)
```